# Attempting to Insert CreatedDate - Field is not writeable: Account.CreatedDate

Tags: datetime, create-records

I am trying to insert a list of records with a CreatedDate of my choosing. I read the documentation about what settings are needed to grant access to insert values for the audit fields.

I have enabled the user interface setting "“Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation” and “Update Records with Inactive Owners” User Permissions" and created a permission set that grants me access.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm

However, I am still getting the error: "Field is not writeable: Account.CreatedDate".

Example script below:

```
List<Account> createddatelist =
[SELECT name, createddate FROM Account WHERE id = '001a000001kXUZT'];

System.debug('createdatelist');

DateTime testdate = DateTime.newInstance(1990, 3, 17);

for(Account acct : createddatelist){

acct.createddate = testdate;
acct.name = 'test of date';

}

insert createddatelist;
```

Comment: Mercury86.. have you try to execute this code from dev console is it working ?

Comment: @sfdcweb Yes, that is were the error is coming from. Mark Keats has answered this question. The documentation above mentions that I can only do it via the API. I still find it strange that I cannot do so via the dev console, but per the documentation Mark Keats is correct.

Comment: Mercury86.... Just now I have tested in my org. I am creating Account record with createdDate 1990 in my apex class it is working... is your permission set set audit checkbox is enabled ?

Comment: @sfdcweb I just tried again now, still the same error. Data Loader did work tho.

Comment: @AllabouttheW: I don't see Created date field in mapping of data loader?

Comment: Try this article Gurmeet, it is a setting to allow them to be set on record creation. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334139&type=1&mode=1&language=en_US

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation' feature only applied to records created using the API, not from Apex code.

Comment: Ah shoot, your right!. It says right there on the documentation.

Comment: Yes. The data loader would work fine.

Comment: @MarkKeats when we try to create Account from dev console? is it an API call ?

Comment: @MarkKeats I just now tried in my org.. I am able to create account from apex code and I also tried to create from dev console. in both scenario it is creating Account.

Comment: @SteelReserve211 where in the SF documentation are you seeing that? I can't find anything that clearly states that you can't do it in Apex.
I tried it in a Trigger in my Summer 23 scratch org and it works there. I guess it might be something that has been enabled since 2016.